# Use or replace chipped PVC fitting?

Tags: plumbing, pvc

[image]

Replacing a toilet flange. Is there enough of the fitting remaining to cleanup and use or do I need to do a full replacement?

Comment: Will depend on how lucky you feel.  The piece is on the floor, so cleaning and gluing is possible, but it will be under the floor and out of sight.  It is low pressure, so it is possible, high pressure supply no way.  For a good nights sleep, I would replace.

Comment: Usually a toilet is a single point connection to the main drain.  The second connection might be concerning to a plumber, but I am not up to plumbing codes.

Comment: Also make sure your new flange is securely attached to the top of the new floor, since this doesn't look like it has support underneath it.